# Checking for partial duplications in a CSV in PHP

Tags: php, loops, csv

I'm having an issue with a memory leak in this code.  What I'm attempting to do is to temporarily upload a rather large CSV file (at least 12k records), and check each record for a partial duplication against other records in the CSV file.  The reason why I say "partial duplication" is because basically if most of the record matches (at least 30 fields), it is going to be a duplicate record.  The code I've written should, in theory, work as intended, but of course, it's a rather large loop and is exhausting memory.  This is happening on the line that contains "array_intersect".

This is not for something I'm getting paid to do, but it is with the purpose of helping make life at work easier.  I'm a data entry employee, and we are having to look at duplicate entries manually right now, which is asinine, so I'm trying to help out by making a small program for this.

Thank you so much in advance!

```
        if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
            if (isset($_FILES["sheetupload"])) {
                $fh = fopen(basename($_FILES["sheetupload"]["name"]), "r+");
                $lines = array();
                $records = array();
                $counter = 0;

                while(($row = fgetcsv($fh, 8192)) !== FALSE ) {
                    $lines[] = $row;
                }

                foreach ($lines as $line) {
                    if(!in_array($line, $records)){
                        if (count($records) > 0) {
                            //check array against records for dupes
                            foreach ($records as $record) {
                                if (count(array_intersect($line, $record)) > 30) {
                                    $dupes[] = $line;
                                    $counter++;
                                }
                                else {
                                    $records[] = $line;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            $records[] = $line;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        $counter++;
                    }
                }


                if ($counter < 1) {
                    echo $counter." duplicate records found. New file not created.";
                }
                else {
                    echo $counter." duplicate records found. New file created as NEWSHEET.csv.";
                    $fp = fopen('NEWSHEET.csv', 'w');
                    foreach ($records as $line) {
                        fputcsv($fp, $line);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: So the script DOES run out of memory, yes?

Comment: if you get it to not blow memory the next thing will probably be blowing the execution time limit

Comment: What actual error message are you getting?

Comment: doing this in php may not be the best option, have you tried some scripting language like python or even bash?

Comment: It says that the allowed memory has been exhausted.

Comment: This is the exact error: "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 36 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\code\index.php on line 36"

Comment: Line 36 is where the array_intersect is happening

Comment: if you want to find exact duplicates of the entries in array you could use this array_count_values($array); it will return an array with the keys and how may times they are found in the array, after that eliminate the keys with value 1 and what are left are duplicates.

Comment: I'm not finding exact duplicates, though, but thank you.

Comment: It might be beneficial to sort the input lines alphabetically for easier comparisons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of possibilities, assuming the script is reaching the memory limit or timing out. If you can access the `php.ini` file, try increasing the `memory_limit` and the `max_execution_time`.

If you can't access the server settings, try adding these to the top of your script:

```
ini_set('memory_limit','256M'); // change this number as necessary
set_time_limit(0); // so script does not time out
```

If altering these settings in the script is not possible, you might try using unset() in a few spots to free up memory:

```
// after the first while loop
unset($fh, $row);
```

and

```
//at end of each foreach loop
unset($line);
```

Comment: I've tried using memory_limit and set_time_limit in addition to unsetting variables already to no avail. Thank you, though!

Comment: OK..maybe you can split the csv into smaller chunks and then merge chunks at end of script. Also try PHPExcel ---> https://github.com/PHPOffice. They use cell caching for memory related issues.